# iPhone pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory: bug?

Tags: iphone

I try to manipulate file in sub directory in my project root directory.

I have folder with name "Basic Usage HTML" and i try this code:

```
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"Basic Usage HTML" ]isDirectory:YES] ]
```

And it's return "nil string parameter"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Xcode's build process isn't including the "Basic Usage HTML" subfolder in your build.

Also, you may want to split each statement out and `NSLog` them to see where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was due to the target not being setup to copy (or compile) the resource when building.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set isDirectory to YES? That looks like the bug here. (Early morning coffee alert)